# pyspark: How can I use multiple `lit(val)` in a computation where `val` is a variable in python?

Tags: pyspark

```
D = # came from numpy.int64 via pandas
E = # came from numpy.int64 via pandas

import pyspark.sql.functions as F

output_df.withColumn("c", F.col("A") - F.log(F.lit(D) - F.lit(E)))
```

I tried to use multiple `lit` inside pyspark with column operation. But I keep getting errors like

```
*** AttributeError: 'numpy.int64' object has no attribute '_get_object_id'
```

But these ones work

```
D=2
output_df.withColumn("c", F.lit(D))
output_df.withColumn("c", F.lit(2))
```

Comment: I think just need to explicitly `int(` the values then it will work

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
df.withColumn("c", F.col("A") - F.log(F.lit(int(D - E))))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
D = int(D)
E = int(E)
```

Just add these two lines and it will work. The issue is that pyspark doesn't know how to handle `numpy.int64`